# SQL Server LEFT Join on all rows withe same ID Same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Thanks for the help in advance.

Given a table

```
ISBN    count    date
9871    5        2013-01-10
9871    8        2013-05-10
9871    10       2014-01-30
6541    11       2012-05-10
6764    05       2013-05-10
6541    07       2013-05-10
```

with a given ISBN (e.g. 9871) i want to join to all rows with the same ISBN without knowing how many times it will appear.It will be used for checking a booking over a period and all the information is in one table.

I basically want the final result to look like.

```
ISBN Count 1 Count 2 Count 3
9871 5       8        10
```

I am new to the forum so let me know if this was answered somewhere else i could not find it by referencing  it the way i understand it.

Comment: What do you imagine the row for 6541 would look like?

Comment: Well for now i would not want it to show because i only want the comparison for one ISBN but it would be handy to do the same thing for all rows but just null or blank if it does not have the same amount of rows. i.e. 6541 appears twice so it will have a value under count 1 and 2 and null or blank for count 3. Then an unrelated question how did you get my post to have spaces and tabs i could not get it tabs i could get line breaks with <br>.

Comment: Try this. The dynamic verion of te answer might help you.

Comment: @Lesley86 Highlighting text in your question and hitting the `{}` symbol will format it as code.

Comment: Search for `PIVOT` and `Dynamic PIVOT` and you should find a number of suitable answers.